# Error submitting iOS .app using TestFlight API

Tags: api, bash, file-upload, testflight

I'm running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
archive=`./builds/myapp.ipa`
curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json
-F file=$archive
-F api_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
-F team_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
-F notes='here comes the new app!' 
-F notify=True
-F distribution_lists='MyFriends'
```

but I'm getting the error:

> You must supply api_token, team_token, the file and notes (missing
>   file)

I'm actually copy/past-ing the script from the TestFlight website. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that, as seen in the example given in [the TestFlight API Documentation](https://testflightapp.com/api/doc/), you need to use the '@' character before the IPA file name.

You should try with:

```
#!/bin/bash
archive=`./builds/myapp.ipa`
curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json \
-F file=@$archive \
-F api_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-F team_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-F notes='here comes the new app!' \
-F notify=True \
-F distribution_lists='MyFriends'
```

Comment: same goes for the dSYM file if you choose to include it.